# I can't sync my music to my new iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I'm trying to move my music from my old iPhone 5 (purchased in the US) to my new iPhone 5s (purchased in Canada). My music is backed up to my iCloud account and basically when I got the new phone I added my Apple account so everything (apps, notes, texts, emails, photos, vids, etc.) and transferred everything except for my music. I've been carrying both phones so I can listen to music but that's really cumbersome.

For whatever reason whenever I tried synching my new phone to my iTunes the playlist names are there but there are no files. When I checked which devices were backed up on my iTunes, it just lists my new iPhone. The files are there in my iTunes library, but I just can't get them to transfer.

If it makes a difference, under settings, and music, there is no option under the library heading on either iPhone to turn on iCloud music library. Moreover, the the little iPhone icon in iTunes that usually pops up when you plug it into your laptop doesn't appear. This is the iTunes icon you click on that lets you access things on your iPhone.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Music. Is "Show Apple Music" switched to "on?"

You cannot have Apple Music enabled and sync your music library. It will only make those songs in your library available via the cloud.

You must choose, for your device, if you want to have Apple Music (which has a paid subscription fee of $9.99 after a trial period) -or- sync your music library.

You can, however, download songs individually onto your device for offline use.